# ArgsTable using propTypes in a StoryBook docs

Tags: reactjs, webpack, documentation, storybook

I'm trying to create a docs for a small component. To do this I'm using StoryBook with the addon "@storybook/addon-docs", but I can't get the component properties to appear.

**My component:**

```js
function OverlayList(props) {...}

OverlayList.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Prop children.....Example 1.
   **/
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
  /**
   * Test .... .
   */
  options: PropTypes.array,
  /**
    Test test test
    */
  selectedValue: PropTypes.string,
};

OverlayList.defaultProps = {
  children: <input></input>,
  options: [],
};

export default OverlayList;
```

**src/components/OverlayList/OverlayList.stories.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import OverlayList from './OverlayList';

export default {
  title: 'OverlayList',
  component: OverlayList,
};

export const overlayList = (args) => {
  return <OverlayList {...args} />;
};
```

**.storybook/main.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/components/**/*.stories.[tj]s'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-docs'],
};
```

Why I can not see the component props with their descriptions?

The component was not create with "create-react-app", I use webpack.

[image]

Thanks you so much for everything.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? Please let me know.